# How to avoid image attachment in html email?

Tags: html-email

I am supposed to send out the newsletter for a local club.  Formatting in HTML appears fine, but if user views the email in a web based client (e.g. yahoo, gmail, etc.), the image also appear separately as an attachment; even though I am using a URL to reference the image.  How can I avoid having the image appear as an attachment? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>Club News</title>

    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #FAFAFA;width: 100%;">

<center>

<table id="table1" style="background-color: #ffffff; border-bottom: 0px none; width: 600px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>
<img style="position: relative; right: 0; bottom: 0;border: 0px none; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; display: block; float: left;" title="Club1" src="http://www.clubswebsite.com/assets/img/clublogo.png" alt="logo" align="center"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution you can use, if your image is relatively simple (such as clip-art or logo), is to convert the image to pure HTML. You can find tools that convert the bitmap to an HTML table, coloring the cells in the pixel's color. Some convertors ([here's one that I wrote](http://img2html.odednoam.com) - source code [here](https://github.com/odednoam/image2html)) apply RLE compression to make sure that HTML isn't too large.

Note, that even with RLE this greatly increases the image size (e.g., a 5kb PNG might grow to be 80kb HTML) but AFAIK, as long as you keep the e-mail size under ~120kb it displays well on all e-mail clients.